# Not able to listen pusher events at client side in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher, inertiajs

I'm using pusher in laravel to broadcast messages. Laravel is able to send message to the pusher channel. But i'm not able to listen to the events at the client side.

I'm using Larave, inertia, vuejs.

I have a created an event NewChatMessage which will broadcast message. and in the show chat i'm using listening to the events, which is not happening.

Bootstrap.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';
window._ = _;

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    wsHost: 'ws-ap2.pusher.com',
    wsPort: 80,
    forceTLS: false,
    enabledTransports: ['ws'],
    cluster:import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    disableStats: true
});
```

NewChatMessage.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use App\Models\Message;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Company;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcastNow;

class NewChatMessage implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    public $user;
    public $company;
    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(User $user,Message $message)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('chat'.$this->message->chatroom_id);
    }

    public function broadcastAs()
    {
        return "message.new";
    }
}
```

Chatroom.vue

```
<script setup>
import { Link, usePage, useForm } from "@inertiajs/inertia-vue3";
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import ReceivedMessageCard from "@/Components/ReceivedMessageCard.vue";
import SentMessageCard from "@/Components/SentMessageCard.vue";
import ClipIcon from "@/Icons/ClipIcon.vue";
import EllipsisHorizontal from "@/Icons/EllipsisHorizontal.vue";
import PaperAirPlaneIcon from "@/Icons/PaperAirPlaneIcon.vue";
import UploadIcon from "@/Icons/UploadIcon.vue";
import UserIcon from "@/Icons/UserIcon.vue";
import ChatRoomLayout from "@/Layouts/ChatRoomLayout.vue";
import axios from "axios";

const props = defineProps({
    confirmsTwoFactorAuthentication: Boolean,
    sessions: Array,
    chatroom: Object,
    messages: Object,
    auth_member: Object,
    readBy: Object,
});

const page = usePage();

const showOptions = ref(false);
const message = ref(null);

const form = useForm({
    file: null,
});

const chatroomMessages = ref(props.messages);
// setInterval(function(){
//     getMessages()
// }, 1000);

onMounted(() => {
    scroll(0);
    connect();
});

const connect = () => {
    window.Echo.private("chat."+props.chatroom.id).listen(".message.new", (e) => {
        console.log("inside");
    });

};

const scroll = (height) => {
    var objDiv = document.getElementById("container");
    objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight + height;
};

const getMessages = async () => {
    await axios
        .get(route("enquiry.chatroom.show", { chatroom: props.chatroom }))
        .then((res) => {
            chatroomMessages.value = res.data;
        });

    scroll(20);
};
const sendMessage = () => {
    if (message.value !== null && message.value !== "") {
        axios
            .post(route("chatroom.newMessage", { id: props.chatroom.id }), {
                message: message.value,
            })
            .then((res) => {
                if (res.status === 201) {
                    message.value = "";
                    getMessages();
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
};
const uploadFile = () => {
    showOptions.value = false;
    form.post(route("chatroom.fileUpload", { id: props.chatroom.id }));
};

const shareDetails = () => {
    message.value =
        "Email: " +
        page.props.value.user.email +
        " Number: " +
        page.props.value.user.number;
    sendMessage();
    showOptions.value = false;
};
</script>
```

Comment: Can you include your `channel.php` routes?

Comment: In your `.env`, what broadcasting driver are you using?